# How to set different desktop resolution while keeping active signal resolution

Tags: windows, display, resolution, gpu

In Windows 10 there are two things called resolution: a desktop resolution and an active signal resolution.

I want to be able to change the resolution of the desktop in Windows 10/11. I have a 1920x1080 monitor and I want to set desktop to be of some resolution that is less than the maximal physical resolution. But when I want to set it for example to 800x600, Windows changes also the active signal resolution.

Is it possible to *separately* control the desktop resolution?

I know you can do it with Nvidia gpus, but I use AMD gpu.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I read about CRU - custom resolution utility - and as I understood, it changes the active signal resolution. Also, tried to set a custom resolution in radeon pro settings, but it says that the resolution I want to set is unsupported. Probably also it tries to change active resolution.